# Running Windows Server 2012 on vSphere 4.1

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, windows-server-2012

I know it's not supported, and won't be officially supported, but has anyone had success getting a Windows Server 2012 VM running on a vSphere 4.1 box?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nope.  Time to upgrade ESX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won’t be able to install this at all. You will need to be running ESXI5 at the very minimum. But I would wait for a few weeks as EXI 5.1 has just been released. 
The hardware version profiles just wont support it at all, and VMware will not write a new hardware profile for it.

Answer (score -2):

I found these set of instructions:

[Windows Server 2012 on ESXi 4.1](https://jgiffard.wordpress.com/2013/06/25/windows-server-2012-on-esxi-4-1/)

Comment: I don't think providing a not supported solution is a good idea. Even more so if the solution would be applied to a productive environment.